# is == operator meant for primitives comparing

Tags: java

It's written all over that `==` checks if two objects share same memory reference or not. Then why am I getting the output `false` in below code?

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Double d1 = new Double(12.0);
        Double d2 = d1;
        d1 = d1 + 1.0;
        System.out.println(d1 == d2);
    }
}
```

Is this due to autoboxing that `Double` gets converted to `double` in line `d1 = d1 + 1.0` and `==` checks primitive values? I am confused. I expected output to be `true`. Can someone clear away my doubts?

Comment: d1 is 13 and d2 is 12 - they are clearly not `==` or `equal`...

Comment: Why do you think they'd be `==` _or even_ `equals()`??

Comment: @assylias but d1 and d2 are reference type. They are not primitives. They are sharing same memory location. Aren't they?

Comment: @JSK: You're creating a *new* `Double` with `d1=d1+1.0;`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder are you saying, Double is immutable like Strings

Comment: @JSK even if that were not the case, the assignment operator on a reference will always change the reference and the plus operator can never mutate an `Object`. So even if you could do `Double.setValue(double)`, what you have done **must** result in a new `Object`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your source of confusion arises from this line:

```
d1 = d1 + 1.0;
```

Lets start from the beginning. Lets call your references to objects `dX` and the objects themselves `oX`.

To start you write:

```
Double d1 = new Double(12.0);
```

So we have a reference `d1` that point to an `Object o1` that is a `Double 12.0`.

Next you write:

```
Double d2 = d1;
```

So now we have a reference `d1` and a reference `d2` that both point to an `Object o1` that is a `Double 12.0`.

Next you write:

```
d1 = d1 + 1.0;
```

So now we have a new object `o2` and we **repoint** the reference `d1` to point at `o2`. Never forget what immutable means, in Java primitive wrapper types are **always** immutable. So to change their value a new wrapper must be created.

So in the end you have

- `d1` pointing to an `Object o2` which is a `Double 13.0`.
- `d2` pointing to an `Object o1` which is a `Double 12.0`.

So you can see that `d1` and `d2` point to completely different objects.

The situation would be the same if using primitive `double` except it would be incorrect to talk about object and references, you would be copying memory.

Comment: Boris. As far as OOP design cannot we look at primitive as objects as well? After all also the wrapped objects have location in memory. Can you clarify your last paragraph?

Comment: @sivi Java is pass by value. So when you do the assignment `d1 = d2`, if we are discussing primitives, the memory location would be _copied_ - this is the same as for a reference but in the reference case the copied reference refers to some other memory location where the object lives. So with primitives, immediately you did the assignment you'd have two primitives.

Answer (score 3):

Your code compares 12 to 13, so the result cannot be `true`. However, even if you added zero, you would get `false`

Due to autoboxing, you can write this expression

```
d1=new Double(d1.doubleValue()+0.0);
```

using this short form

```
d1=d1+0.0;
```

But really you are creating a new object of type `Double`, so `==` returns `false`.

Comment: is `d1=d1+0.0` creating new Double object

Comment: @JSK yes. Because `Double` is immutable.

Comment: @BoristheSpider So Double is immutable like Strings. OK. So now I understand the scene. I never know this thing that Double is Immutable

Comment: @JSK what ever made you think that they are mutable? And how did you expect the plus operator (which acts on primitives) to mutate an object?

Comment: @JSK All wrapper objects used in autoboxing numerics are immutable. Even `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` numeric classes are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

I will try answering your question:

d2 value is 12.0 and d1 value is 13.0. when you change the value of d1 it creats a new reference to a different object. d1 and d2 were references to same object but now they are references to different objects that hold a unique value.

Also from a software maintnance Point of view if all objects change when you change a different variable name it is harder to maintain because you will have to know where all the variable assignments and keep track of them.

Answer (score 0):

There is an implicit conversion from Double to double when it comes to operations. The same goes for Integer and Float. Double is a class that adds functionalities to the primitive type double. e.g: you can do ArrayList but not ArrayList.